# How to set img attributes with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project (web application).
There is a lot of images.
For a SEO purposes I need to set width and height attributes in each img tag.
So I need to do something like that:

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

images.forEach(img => {
  // Here need is magic
  // I need to set here for each img, width and height attributes of img
})
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The snippet editor has four parts. Each with a label that tells you what part of a site is meant to be added there. Why did you add your script in the HTML section? o.O Have a look at -> [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: `img.setAttribute(...)`

Comment: `img.setAttribute('width', ...);` but that won't work for SEO; you have to do it on the server. Web crawlers usually don't run JS before evaluating the page; they just look at the initial HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The code will look like this

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
images.forEach(img => {
  img.setAttribute('key', 'value');
});
```

Comment: yes exactly, in my situation it will be something like that:
img.setAttribute('width', HERE I NEED VALUE);

Comment: @Smith — There's no way you can determine what the value should be with client-side JS until it is *far too late* to make any kind of difference.

Comment: @Quentin so what do u think i need to do: 
My task is:
I need define width and height of all img on site

Comment: Edit the HTML (in whatever way makes sense for however the HTML is created in the first place).